# Exception preparing module:EJB Module. run-as security principal chosen for EJB is not a valid user principal in the current security realm

Tags: linux, java-7, weblogic12c

I have one ear file to be deployed in Weblogic 12c generic with jdk_1_7_51 in Linux 64 bit machine. While deploying I am facing `Exception praparing Module: EJB Module`.

I know this is because of `run-as security principal, 'Superuser'`.

I have encountered with one post facing the same issue. https://community.oracle.com/thread/2178653?tstart=0.

But I have already a user named 'Superuser' in realm. Also I have a group with the same name. 
Still I am facing the same issue.

I also read that jdk_17_51 version had restricted some packages due to security reasons. But I don't know how to resolve my issue.

i have been struggling from one week. Please help me.

I am attaching screen shot of my weblogic admin console[image]

Anybody please help me.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a WL cache error. We use the same application server for all of the branches, and switching from one branch (same deployment name etc) to another caused the problem. Try deleting your WL "tmp" and "cache" directories before a cold start.