# Weblogic doesn't start because of "Authentication denied"

Tags: java, weblogic

I had to change a Data Source configuration to solve a Runtime error (connection string wasn't specified).

The error:

```
Unable to deploy EJB: MailService from wps.jar:
The run-as security principal, 'portaladmin', chosen for the EJB 'MailService(Application: my-application, EJBComponent: wps.jar)' is not a valid user principal in the current security realm. Please specify a valid user principal for the EJB to use.
```

As I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36404281/11961036), I tried stopping the Managed server and cleaning those folders. On restarting the Managed, both using the script and the GUI, it started throwing me this error:

```
weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication denied: Boot identity not valid; The user name and/or password from the boot identity file (boot.properties) is not valid. The boot identity may have been changed since the boot identity file was created. Please edit and update the boot identity file with the proper values of username and password. The first time the updated boot identity file is used to start the server, these new values are encrypted
```

I started browsing for a solution, and everyone says I need to delete both the `servers/MyServer/data/ldap` folder and the `servers/MyServer/security/boot.properties`. None of this works. Also, even the AdminServer is not starting for the same reason. The NodeManager, instead, runs smoothly.

I already tried resetting the username and password, like so:

```
cd $DOMAIN_HOME/bin
. ./setDomainEnv.sh
cd ../security
java weblogic.security.utils.AdminAccount user password .
```

Tried running the server manually prompting user and password, but the exception persists.

Also tried rolling back the setting I made previously, even though it has nothing to do with WebLogic users.. but nothing.

**Important notes:**

- I really would like to avoid freshly reinstalling the environment.
- I cannot reboot the server.
- I need those `boot.properties`, either I'm not able to launch WebLogic processes in the background.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

Looks like WebLogic tries to connect to every DataSource on startup.
I did modify a DataSource before shutting down the Managed, but I wrote the connection string wrongly (even though I copied it from another WebLogic server):

Indeed, what I did write was:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:XEPDB
```

What I had to write, instead, was:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521/XEPDB
```

This prevented WebLogic to start correctly.

Fixed the connection string in `$DOMAIN_NAME/config/jdbc/my_datasource.xml` and ran smoothly.